# Error queriedo subir archivo con angular

Tags: angular, postman, http-post, cabeceras-http, binary-files

Buenas noches espero puedan ayudarme, estoy tratando de enviar un archivo a mi backend , pero al momento de hacer la peticion la respuesta me marca el siguiente error:

```
"detail": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported"
}
```

La cosa es que en Postman sí contesta sin problema y solo al querer usar el servicio en la aplicación no me responde, les adjunto la parte del código donde hago las petición

```
  upload(event: any) { //método donde preparo los datos para la petición
const request: TypeIdentificacion = {
  tipo_documento: "CREDENCIALES_PARA_VOTAR",
  formato: "JPG", id_cliente: '123',
  rfc: 'ABC123', razon_social: 'hh',
  curp: 'uu', id_documento: 'jjj',
  vigencia: 'ddd'
}
const file: File = event.target.files[0];
if (file) {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('files', file)
  formData.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(request))

  this.mediaSer.uploadFile(formData)
    .subscribe({
      next: resp => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Exito",
          text: "Documento subido exitosamente!!!",
        })
      },
      error: e => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Error!!!",
          text: "Error subiendo el archivo",
        })
      }
    })
}
}



 uploadFile(formData: FormData): Observable<any> { //metodo hacia el servicio
const opciones = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    /*      'Content-Type':'application/json', */
    'accept': 'application/json'
  })
};
const response = this.hhtp.post<FormData>(
  `${this.url}/ocr/contactos`,
  formData, opciones
);
return response;
}
```

este es el html del imput

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="File" class="form-label">Identificación</label>
      <input type="file"  class="form-control" accept="pdf/*" (change)="upload($event)"
        id="identifiacion" formControlName="identifiacion" [ngClass]="{
          'is-invalid': f.identifiacion.errors && error==true}" aria-describedby="identifiacion-error">
      <span *ngIf="f.identifiacion.errors?.required  && error==true" id="identifiacion-error"
        class="error invalid-feedback">Por favor añada el archivo solicitado</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la implementación del `this.mediaSer.uploadFile`. Saludos.

Comment: ahí esta el uploadFile solo que para no pegar toda el archivo solo pegue el método

Comment: En ese caso, buena suerte, no puedo hacer más. A alguien más se le ocurrirá algo.

Answer (score -1):

Parece que hay un ligero error de tipeo:

Presta atención al `type`

```
<input type="file"  class="form-control" accept="pdf/*" (change)="upload($event)"
        id="identifiacion" formControlName="identifiacion" [ngClass]="{
          'is-invalid': f.identifiacion.errors && error==true}" aria-describedby="identifiacion-error">
```

Reemplaza:

```
formData.append('files', file)
```

Por:

```
formData.append('file', file);
```

Comment: hola la cosa es que para el backend así nos lo pide, nos solicitan dos atributos en el formdata , con ese nombre justo, así que no creo que valla por ahí, aun así lo probé como dices pero me sigue marcando lo mismo